# Fetching the entity attributes values in Dynamics-CRM using web api query

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

I got a task to make a search page(HTML) in which there are two `drop downs` and one `textbox` and one `grid` in which data is loaded dynamically(I am using JQuery and Web API queries to dynamically fetch data).

First `dropdown` box will contain all the entities of CRM and after selecting entity from first `dropdown` box the second `dropdown` box will be updated with attributes names(column names in entity which are Custom) and the grid will be loaded with the attributes and their values.

I created a Web API query to fetch the Custom Attributes but i am not able to fetch the values of the attribute in single query.

I created this query to fetch the Custom Attributes. But i am not able to get the values of the attribute. In this query the `test_policy` is dynamically fetched.

```
https://halfstack.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='test_policy')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=Attributes($select=LogicalName,AttributeType,DisplayName;$filter=AttributeType ne Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeTypeCode'Lookup'and AttributeType ne Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeTypeCode'Customer' and IsCustomAttribute eq true)
```

I created this query to get the value of the attributes but i am not able to fetch only the Custom Attributes of the entity. This query fetches all the attributes of the entity.

```
https://halfstack.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/test_policies?$select=*
```

I want to fetch the Custom Columns with their Values in a single API query.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Within the CRM Database there are two types of data:

- Business Data (Accounts, Contacts, Leads, data from Custom Entities,
  etc.)
- Meta Data (Entity definitions, attributes definitions,
  relationship definitions) - basically the data that is needed to
  model the CRM Business Data and the relationship between the business
  data tables. The MetaData is what you get when you export a solution

From a data perspective, the entries in the MetaData tables and the Business Data tables are independent from each other, so there is no way to join these tables so that you can get the Display Name of the Attributes and the Field Values from an Entity in the same request. You need to do separate requests.

Microsoft also documents this as separated requests (query data and query metadata):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/query-metadata-web-api
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/query-data-web-api

To answer your other question, related to how to fetch only the fields you are interested in, you can pass these as parameters to the select system query option, as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/query-data-web-api#request-specific-properties

In your case this could look like https://halfstack.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/test_policies?$select=new_field1,new_field2,new_field3,_new_lookupfield_value and so on